# `__unicode__()` addition not working in basic poll application in Django tutorial

Tags: django

I'm working through the Django tutorial after having installed the development source of Django along with PostgreSQL from source and everything else needed from source. I'm trying to do everything with python3 instead of python on Ubuntu 12.10.

Everything seemed to be going well until I got to the part in the tutorial where we're supposed to redefine `__unicode__()` in order to return a sensible result when we ask for objects.all() from a table. It's not working at all. I decided to try `__str__()`, and it worked!

But, the tutorial explains we're not supposed to redefine `__str__()`. So, what's wrong with my install that `__unicode__()` doesn't work while `__str__()` does? Other methods from the tutorial work fine.

Comment: You should know that Python3 isn't yet officially supported in Django.

Comment: Version 1.6 will officially support python3 and I'm using 1.6 alpha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are handled differently in Python 3 vs 2.

In 2, `__str__()` returned bytes, while `__unicode__()` returned characters.  In 3, `__str__()` now returns characters, as strings are now natively unicode, and `__unicode__()` doesn't exist.  If you really need the old 2 behavior for `__str__()`, I believe it is now `__bytes__()`.

Short answer, stick with `__str__()` if you are using Python 3, and realize that the Django tutorials explicitly state they are written for 2.x, so there will be differences.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might be something more because people over a year ago were having the same problem and nobody answered their question properly (this was on google groups for django users).  Would be nice if the tutorial added comments for python3 differences though.